# Change value Using button click event in DynamicRadioGroupModel in ng Dynamic Forms

Tags: typescript, angular6, ng-bootstrap, dynamicform

I'm using the ng-dynamic-form (6.0.4),NG Bootstrap with angular 6. 
my question is very simple.

I'm trying to change the value in DynamicRadioGroupModel when button click event triggered, I'm using
"setValue()" method as below. My problem is after setting value into FormController UI doesn't change.
Help me to figure it out

```
new DynamicRadioGroupModel({

        id: "payment",
        label: "Payment Method",
        options: [
            {
                label: "Credit Card",
                value: "cc"
            },
            {
                label: "PayPal",
                value: "paypal"
            },
            {
                label: "Cash",
                value: "cash"
            },
            {
                label: "Bitcoin",
                value: "bitcoin"
            }
        ],
        value: "cc"
    })
```

```
test(){

    this.formGroup.get("payment").setValue("cash");

  }
```

```
<div class="overflow-hidden content-margin container-fluid" style="width: 50%;">

<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="formGroup">

    <dynamic-ng-bootstrap-form-control *ngFor="let formModelCtrl of formModel"
                               [group]="formGroup"
                               [layout]="formLayout"
                               [model]="formModelCtrl"
                               (blur)="onBlur($event)"
                               (change)="onChange($event)"
                               (focus)="onFocus($event)"
                               (ngbEvent)="onNgbEvent($event)"></dynamic-ng-bootstrap-form-control>

</form>

<button (click)="test()" type="button">Test</button>

<pre>{{formGroup.value | json}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

for updating values, you should use the 'valueUpdates' Subject from your DynamicFormsModel, in your case this here should work::

```
   const radioGroup: DynamicRadioGroupModel<string> = 
this.dynamicFormService.findById('payment', this.formModel) as 
DynamicRadioGroupModel<string>; radioGroup.valueUpdates.next('cc');
```

'dynamicFormService' is the one you used to create your form group from the model.

regarding git hub raised an [issue](https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms/issues/803) .